# How do I create Free Extents, so I can replace a physical drive in this lvm Volume Group?

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm

I have a Fedora Linux 28 system with 4 physical drives all in one `LVM Volume Group`. This system's motherboard only has 4 SATA slots. My goal is to remove the `/dev/sdd` physical drive from the Volume Group. I set this LVM Volume Group up during the installation of Fedora and I haven't made any changes to it since.

`sudo lvm pvdisplay -m` outputs the following:

```
 --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb2
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               <148.05 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              37900
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          37900
  PV UUID               VWJMSa-pvQ2-7Ih8-viHe-buy2-PYJC-GEefBa

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 37899:
    Logical volume  /dev/fedora/root
    Logical extents 76310 to 114209

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               <74.53 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              19079
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          19079
  PV UUID               fiknY0-2s1A-tk8S-TLBz-WH2E-DAjH-DdSEoD

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 19078:
    Logical volume  /dev/fedora/root
    Logical extents 114210 to 133288

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdd1
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               <74.53 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              19079
  Free PE               1
  Allocated PE          19078
  PV UUID               nIeix3-CrhC-BM3o-ZBFU-xowH-h2MS-LohQZ6

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 18082:
    Logical volume  /dev/fedora/root
    Logical extents 133289 to 151371
  Physical extent 18083 to 19077:
    Logical volume  /dev/fedora/swap
    Logical extents 0 to 994
  Physical extent 19078 to 19078:
    FREE

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda1
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               <298.09 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              76310
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          76310
  PV UUID               emQpJu-VuAs-20mU-KcJz-d8Wu-wAJK-8caUof

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 76309:
    Logical volume  /dev/fedora/root
    Logical extents 0 to 76309
```

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/removeadisk.html), which describes how to use the `pvmove` command, but running `pvmove /dev/sdd1` gives me this error:

```
No extents available for allocation.
```

How do I create extents for the allocation process?

### EDIT

`lvm pvs`

```
PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
/dev/sda1  fedora lvm2 a--  <298.09g    0
/dev/sdb2  fedora lvm2 a--  <148.05g    0
/dev/sdc1  fedora lvm2 a--   <74.53g    0
/dev/sdd1  fedora lvm2 a--   <74.53g 4.00m
```

`lvm lvs`

```
LV   VG     Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root fedora -wi-ao---- <591.30g
  swap fedora -wi-ao----   <3.89g
```

`lvm vgs`

```
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  fedora   4   2   0 wz--n- <595.19g 4.00m
```

### EDIT 2

`df -Th`

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root ext4      582G  443G  110G  81% /
```

Comment: you have to add new disk, you only have 1 (one) extend free. `pvmove` will only work if there is a free disk to "receive" moved extents.

Comment: @Archemar Do you mean a new physical drive? I can't do that, as I'm already using all available SATA slots. I have >75GB free, so is it possible to use that free space in the `pvmove`?

Comment: You must first delete or shrink some existing LVs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have edited the original to show the output of `lvm lvs`

Comment: And your root filesystem is probably XFS, which can't be shrunk. You somehow dug a hole for yourself here. You're going to have to add another disk, at least temporarily.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm pretty sure my filesystem is `ext4`. Please see `EDIT 2` in my original post.

Comment: Oh, well, in that case you can just do it the usual way. No problem.